# Show a loader during the user log in process

Tags: meteor

I'm using the Accounts API to manage users. My app first tries to log in a user using their credentials, and in case that results in an error, it creates a new user account using the input credentials.

```js
// Log the user in
Meteor.loginWithPassword(username, token, function(error) {
    if(error) { // create a new user account, log them in and show the page
        Accounts.createUser({
            username: username,
            email: username + '@example.com',
            password: token,
            profile: {name: username}
        }, showThePage);
    }
    else { // show the page
        //showThePage();
        window.location.reload();
    }
});
```

But this code block executes only when the user was previously logged out from their browser, and if that is the case it takes 2-3 seconds for Meteor to log the user in using `loginWithPassword`. As I'm using v0.5.0, there is no `Meteor.loggingIn()`, and the only thing I have is `Meteor.userLoaded()`. Meteor, for some reason, performs the login operation twice -- once by loading a placeholder user (that has only its userId property set) and again by loading the actual user. This makes userLoaded() return `true` twice, because of which my loader image doesn't work as expected.

Also notice that in the else block inside loginWithPassword, I'm doing a window reload. I've a function `showThePage()` which contains all the template data & event binding code. That function retrieves data using the username of the logged in user. Now because when that function in else block executes there isn't a  real user logged in (remember meteor takes time to log the user in), no data gets fetched.

Is there a workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

First of all Meteor.userLoaded goes away after you upgrade beyond 0.5.0. You should check if Meteor.userId() === null to know if the user login has completed, which works in 0.5.0 and beyond. It may get called multiple times, as you have noted, but only when it has a real value has the login completed.

Answer (score 0):

If you really can't update to 0.5.1, use a session variable to store `loggingIn` in between the call to `loginWithPassword` and the callback.

```
Session.set('loggingIn',true);
Meteor.loginWithPassword(...
  Session.set('loggingIn',false);
});
```

Then, use the `Session.get('loggingIn')` call where appropriate.

Want to adapt `userLoaded()` instead?

```
var userLoadedTimes = 0; // can't use session variable because it would mess up reactive context on increments
Session.set('loggingIn',false);
Meteor.autorun(function () {
  var userLoaded = Meteor.userLoaded(); // reactive.
  if (userLoaded)
    userLoadedTimes++;
  if ((userLoadedTimes % 2 == 0) && (userLoadedTimes != 0))
    Session.set('loggingIn',true);
  else
    Session.set('loggingIn',false);
});
```

What's that modulo doing there? Well if `userLoaded` has called a reactive context twice for some reason, you have actually logged in. So we check if `userLoadedTimes` is a multiple of two/even. All other times, i.e., when `userLoadedTimes` is odd (`userLoadedTimes % 2 == 1`), we're looking at the fake user... which means we're still loading the real user!

If this doesn't work, apply the even/odd logic to the first solution using session variable changes on the callback, in the event Meteor calls the `loginWithPassword` callback twice.